# generate random numbers on 3 different images

Tags: android, random

I have 3 images in which i want to generate random numbers. There is an array of numbers minimum is 0 and maximum is 9. The random number is getting generated once but not again.

Code...

```
int r;
int min_ran=0;
int max_ran=9;

random.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            r = ran.nextInt(max_ran - min_ran + 1) + min_ran;
            img1.setImageResource(images[image1+1]);
            img2.setImageResource(images[image1-1]);
            img3.setImageResource(images[(image1+1)*1]);
        }
    });
```

Please help

Comment: ok. `r` is your random number, but you're accessing `images[image1+1]`. where are you using the random number? -> try `images[r+1]` if you're having random numbers to display them on top of the images, you'll need either a custom imageview, or a textview on top of them, to which you then post your number.

Comment: It's not very clear what You trying to do `img1.setImageResource(images[image1+1]);
 img2.setImageResource(images[image1-1]);
 img3.setImageResource(images[(image1+1)*1]);` `img3` is the same as `img1`. Also You can use `r = ran.nextInt(10);` if You want to generate random number from 0-9

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Select 3 image resources randomly?

Comment: Where are you using **r** after getting it?

Comment: Thanks @damian Its working. But after a certain number of clicks it gives me an error of force close. Out of bound exception

Comment: Can you post the logcat output? It's most likely ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You will have to check, that your random value +1 or -1 is still within the array.

Comment: @Terry yes I want to select three images randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to select 3 images randomly (in range from 0 to 9)

```
random.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       img1.setImageResource(images[ran.nextInt(10)]);
       img2.setImageResource(images[ran.nextInt(10)]);
       img3.setImageResource(images[ran.nextInt(10)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This one may give you the same numbers, resulting in having the same image twice. I assumed you don't want this, see my answer below.

Comment: As it's stated in comment above the goal is to select three images randomly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to set 3 different image resources to your 3 images, and select them from an array of image resources called `images[]`. To randomly select 3 images that are different from each other, you can do something like this:

```
private Random randomGenerator = new Random();

random.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int firstIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        int secondIndex = newDifferentRandomNumber(firstIndex);
        int thirdIndex = newDifferentRandomNumber(firstIndex, secondIndex);
        img1.setImageResource(images[firstIndex]);
        img2.setImageResource(images[secondIndex]);
        img3.setImageResource(images[thirdIndex]);
    }
});

/**
 * Generates a new random number that is different from the given one.
 */
private int newDifferentRandomNumber(int number) {
    // generate a random int between 0 and 9
    int newDifferentRandomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    // check if it is equal to the given number, if yes repeat recursively
    if (newDifferentRandomNumber == number) {
        newDifferentRandomNumber = newDifferentRandomNumber(number);
    }
    return newDifferentRandomNumber;
}

/**
 * Generates a new random number that is different from the 2 given ones.
 */
private int newDifferentRandomNumber(int oneNumber, int anotherNumber) {
    // generate a random int between 0 and 9
    int newDifferentRandomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    // check if it is equal to one of the given numbers, 
    // if yes repeat recursively
    if (newDifferentRandomNumber == number 
            || newDifferentRandomNumber == anotherNumber) {
        newDifferentRandomNumber = newDifferentRandomNumber(number);
    }
    return newDifferentRandomNumber;
}
```